# How to load a video in for Woocommerce main product image

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and Wordpress.. I implemented a script that changes the main image on the single product page depending on which thumbnail is clicked.  I also purchased a premium plugin and tweaked a bit for displaying videos on that single product page.

Currently when the user clicks a thumbnail the main image will change according to the thumbnail that is being clicked.  If the  thumbnail has a video attached to it then the video will show in place of the main image.  My problem is that if someone clicks on another thumbnail after viewing the video I cannot bring that main image back in.

Here is my JS so far:

```
(function( $ ){
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('*[data-videolink=""]').removeAttr('data-videolink');


   if($('a[data-videolink]').length > 0){
   var video_code = $('.images a[data-videolink]:first').data('videolink');
  //$('.images a.woocommerce-main-image').html('<iframe src ="'+ video_code +'" width="500" height="300" frameborder="no"></iframe>');

  $('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var photo_fullsize = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x75','');
    $('.images img:first').attr('src',photo_fullsize);
  });


  $('a[data-videolink]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   video_code = $(this).data('videolink');
  //$('.images a[data-videolink]:first').html('<iframe src ="'+ video_code +'" width="500" height="300" frameborder="no"></iframe>');
  $('.images a.woocommerce-main-image').html('<iframe src ="'+ video_code +'" width="500" height="300" frameborder="no"></iframe>');

  $('.thumbnails .thumb-img').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var photo_fullsize = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x75','');
    $('.images a.woocommerce-main-image').html('<img width="800" height="600" src="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/my-main-image-800x600.jpg" class="main-img wp-post-image">');
  });

  $('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var photo_fullsize = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('-100x75','');
    //$('.images img:first').attr('src',photo_fullsize);
  });
});

 };


 });
})(jQuery);
```

This is what the markup looks like on the page:

```
<div class="images">

    <a href="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Chinese_6Pak_Gift_Set.jpg" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="800" height="600" src="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Main-Image-1.jpg" class="main-img wp-post-image" ></a>

        <div class="thumbnails">
            <a href="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Thumb-1.jpg" class="zoom thumb-img first"  rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="100" height="75" src="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Thumb-1.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail"> </a>
            <a href="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Thumb-2.jpg" class="zoom thumb-img" title="Spanish_6Pak_Gift_Set" rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="100" height="75" src="Thumb-2.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail"> </a>

            <a href="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Video-Thumb-3.png" class="zoom video first" data-videolink="//player.vimeo.com/video/74934952?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="100" height="75" src="http://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Video-Thumb-3.png" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" /></a>
        </div>

</div>
```

I am so close!  as you can see I have hardcoded a main image to be brought back in after viewing the video and clicking on another thumbnail, this obviously will not work so in place of that what can I do to repopulate that main image with the main image of the thumbnail that is being clicked.

Comment: You would need some sort of video player to handle the video, similar to what pretty photo is doing.

Comment: Sorry, video player is vimeo -- the plugin inserts a custom field in the product gallery upload where the user can insert the link to the video.

Comment: and the plugin converts it to an iframe or whatever to play the video? What plugin is it?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia the plugin is found here: http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-video-links-product-embedded-videos/5633493

Yes from what I can tell the plugin just converts that into an iframe in a lightbox, but I have tried reaching out to the author to see how I can bypass the lightbox (probably just remove the plugins main.js file) I feel like I am so close, now I just need a way to get the video embed to load in the main images div in place of the main graphic.. Been working at this allll day, brains fried

Comment: Can you paste the HTML of the actual lightbox ( the iframe ) with its surroundings?  Maybe we can target it with jQuery, capture its html, and input it back into the image.

Comment: Hey @JacobRaccuia I updated my question, I pecked away at this last night and am so so close...  Only problem I have having now is bringing back in that main image after clicking away from the video..

Comment: If a user clicks outside of the box, you wouldn't want the video to stop playing, as that would hinder the experience.  Do you have to revert back?  They are aware they played the video so they won't be confused.  If anything, maybe if they watch the whole video would they expect to see a default image again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the developer of the original plugin I am using I got it resolved for what I was needing to accomplish -- This is the final piece of code that tied it all together.  Thanks for the help guys.

```
$('.thumbnails a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   video_code = $(this).data('videolink');
   var image_src = $(this).attr('href');
    if(video_code != null){
  $('.images a:first').html('<iframe src ="'+ video_code +'" width="420" height="315" frameborder="no"></iframe>');
  }else{
    $('.images a:first').html('<img width="800" height="600" class="main-img wp-post-image" src="'+ image_src  +'" />');
  }
});
```